# Plugin stopped working after jQuery 2.2.0 update

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have small scrollspy snippet to observe scrolling events within DOM

Snippet works fine untill jQuery 2.1.4 but not with lastest jQuery 2.2.0

Code is as follow :

```
// Cache selectors
var lastId,
    topMenu = $("#top-menu"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
    // All list items
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
    // Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
      var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
      if (item.length) { return item; }
    });

// Bind click handler to menu items
// so we can get a fancy scroll animation
menuItems.click(function(e){
  var href = $(this).attr("href"),
      offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
  $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
      scrollTop: offsetTop
  }, 300);
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
   // Get container scroll position
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

   // Get id of current scroll item
   var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
     if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
       return this;
   });
   // Get the id of the current element
   cur = cur[cur.length-1];
   var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

   if (lastId !== id) {
       lastId = id;
       // Set/remove active class
       menuItems
         .parent().removeClass("active")
         .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("active");
   }                   
});
```

I tried debugging but it throws

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href=#baz]
```

Here is the jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/up4nu/5473/

What updates in latest jQuery 2.2.0 must have caused this error ?

Comment: Does this help? `[href="#baz"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape `#` sign. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/up4nu/5474/).

```
end().filter("[href=\"#"+id+"\"]").parent().addClass("active");
```

Alternatively you could use `\\#`. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/up4nu/5476/).

```
end().filter("[href=\\#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("active");
```

Comment: Don't you think this had to fail in any version on `jQuery` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre Original code actually works ok with jquery 2.1.4.

Comment: @Yuki, Just tested that and I'm amazed...You need to mention that it is version specific though it does not appear so..